# ¿Cómo crear un objeto DateTime y mostrarlo en un input tipo date?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un problema al querer mostrar el `DateTime` en un input date. La cuestión es que yo traigo de la base de datos una fecha mediante una consulta por parametro y lo guardo en un objeto haciendo:

```
usuario.FechaDeNacimiento = Convert.ToDateTime(tablaResultado.Rows[0]["FechaDeNacimiento"]);
```

Luego en el controller creo un manager, ejecuto la consulta y los datos del objeto se los paso al `viewbag`.

En esa vista tengo un `input="date"` y trate de mostrarlo con el `value="@ViewBag...."` pero no funciona.

Alguna ayuda o sugerencia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagino que en tu vista tienes algo así:

```
<input type="date" value="@ViewBag.Fecha" />
```

El problema es que para inicializar el valor de un `input` tipo fecha (en los navegadores que lo soportan), tienes que pasar el valor en el formato específico año-mes-día o no será reconocido como una fecha válida.  Entonces en tu *controller* necesitas convertir la fecha en un *string*:

```
var fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(tablaResultado.Rows[0]["FechaDeNacimiento"]);
ViewBag.Fecha = fecha.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: Cuando paso la variable y el viewbag al controller me tira que tablaResultado no existe en el contexto.

        public ActionResult EditarUsuario(string ID)
        {
            UsuariosManager manager = new UsuariosManager();
            Usuario usuarios = manager.Consultar(ID);
            var fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(tablaResultado.Rows[0]["FechaDeNacimiento"]);
            ViewBag.Fecha = fecha.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            ViewBag.usuarios = usuarios;
            return View();
        }

Comment: @Popplar ahora que veo tu código es un poco más claro (deberías incluirlo en tu pregunta).  Si el valor lo has guardado en el objeto `usuario.FechaDeNacimiento` entonces deberías usar eso en lugar de `tablaResultado`, ¿cierto? :)

Comment: Muchas gracias @Equiso, lo pude hacer funcionar :)!!
Gracias por la data, no sabia que habia que convertir la fecha en un string para poder usarlo en el input.

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes crear un modelo utilizando *data annotations*

```
public class Usuario {
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime FechaDeNacimiento { get; set }
}
```

Luego en la vista agregar ademas tu vista tiene que estar fuertemente tipada

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FechaDeNacimiento)
```

Comment: Esta solución no la entendi muy bien, de todos modos gracias igual! Al final lo hice como dijo Equiso y lo pude hacer funcionar.

Comment: @Popplar en ese caso por favor marca la respuesta de Equiso como correcta